# how to count frequency for a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

Hi im trying to count the frequency of a 2d array . i  am trying to display the frequency in a certain way for example if a table is like :

0:   1      2    0

1:   2      0    1

2:   1      0    2

i want to be able to count the frequency like :

0: 0      2     1

1: 2      0     1

2: 1      1     1

so the way that the table would should is how many times 0 has appeared in the first column and how many times 1 has a appears in the first column and then so on.

the code i have so far for this is

```
    for (int t = 0; t<s;t++)
    {
        int count= 0 ; 
        for (int p = 0; p<s; p++)
        {
            if(table[p][t] ==p )
            {
                count++

            }
            else if(t+1 != s)
                continue;
            else 
                table[p][t] = count; 
                count = 0;
        }
    }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: I'd suggest using a HashMap for each column indexed with the value of the number in the column, with the value incremented each time that number appears.

Comment: What's the issue are you having?

Comment: my output isn't correct it is not correctly displaying the frequency

Comment: Is your array only going to have 0, 1, and 2? Or it could have any numbers?

Comment: it is suppose to count up the values in each column so for column 1 0 appear 1 time 1 appear 2 times and 2 appear once
Table

0: 1 2 0

1: 2 0 1

2: 1 0 2


Frequency

0: 0 2 1

1: 2 0 1

2: 1 1 1

Answer (score 0):

For each column, make a `HashMap<int, int>`. The key will be the entry, the value will be the frequency in that column, e.g. for that column:

1) iterate over the elements of that column

2) for every element of the column, if it exists in the hashmap as a key already, get its value, increment it by one and add the new value under the same key. If it has not been added yet, add it with value 1

Make an `ArrayList<HashMap<int, int>>` to contain one of these for each column.

You could also keep a `HashMap<int, int>` that counts how many times an element has appeared globally. That way, if you want to preserve the property that every element has a count for every column, even if its count is 0 for that column, you can use this global `HashMap` to go through and add the keys in every column's H`ashMap` that don't exist yet.

`HashMap` is a data structure that allows you to associate a value with every key, and you can add as many entries as you like unlike an array, and the entries don't have to have keys that are successive integers. `ArrayList` is like an array but you can add to and remove from it to change the number of elements that are contained in it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: is it possible to use counters?

Comment: @brian Chiem This is using counters, just that you check if the counter exists in the hashmap (is there a key for the current element?) and if not, create it before using it.

Answer (score 0):

If the example you posted is what the array is always going to be like (i.e. the only values possible are 0, 1, and 2) then you can do something as follows -

```
int[][] counts = new int[3][3]; //this inits all the elements to 0
//iterate through all the elements in your source array
for(int row=0; row<source.length; row++) {
    for(int col=0; col<source[row].length; col++) {     
        //just increment the appropriate element of the counts array here       
        counts[col][source[row][col]]++; 
    }
}
```