# array not working properly

Tags: java, arrays

Hi im trying to count the frequency of a 2d array . i am trying to display the frequency in a certain way for example if a table is like :

0: 1 2 0

1: 2 0 1

2: 1 0 2

i want to be able to count the frequency like :

0: 0 2 1

1: 2 0 1

2: 1 1 1

so the way that the table would should is how many times 0 has appeared in the first column and how many times 1 has a appears in the first column and then so on. i am not sure what the problem that i have . i notice that one it gets to the 2nd iteration it stops working or it just gives out 0

the code i have so far for this is

```
    for (int col =0; col< s ; col++){
        System.out.print(col+ ": ");
        for (int row = 0; row<s; row++)
        {
            x=val[row][col];
            if (table[row][col]==row)
            {
                System.out.print(x++ + " ");
            }

            //System.out.print(val[col][row]+" ");
            if (row+1==s)
                System.out.println();
        }
    }




}
```

thanks

Comment: How is this question different from your original one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893431/how-to-count-frequency-for-a-2d-array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming a regular shaped array.
To make it more robust you would want to detect maximum number of columns.

```
int[][] table = new int[][]{{1,2,0},{2,0,1},{1,0,2}};
int[][] result = new int[table.length][table.length];
for (int row = 0; row<result.length;row++){
  Arrays.fill(result[row], 0);
}

// iterating through multi dimensional arrays it is easier to start
// with dimension 0
for (int row = 0; row<table.length;row++){
  for (int col =0; col< table[row].length ; col++){
    // the row in the result table equals the value of the cell.
    int index = table[row][col];
    result[index][col]++;
  }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```